# Rotating graphics

Tags: java, awt, java-2d, graphics2d

I am trying to make a bullet class. When it is called it will get a direction and an initial position. The problem is the direction is not working it only goes up no matter what I set as the direction.

Please Help.

Thanks in advance

```
public class Bullet extends JComponent implements ActionListener{

private int bx,by;
private double theta;
private double BvelX, BvelY;
private Timer timer = new Timer(8,this);

public Bullet(int bx, int by, double theta)
{
    this.bx = bx;
    this.by = by;
    this.theta = theta;

    BvelX = 0;
    BvelY = -1;

    timer.start();
    revalidate();
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D graphicsS = (Graphics2D) g;

    graphicsS.rotate(theta, bx, by);
    graphicsS.setColor(Color.RED);
    graphicsS.fillOval(bx, by,  8, 8);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    bx += BvelX;
    by += BvelY;

    /*by += 5*(Math.sin(theta));
    bx += 5*(Math.cos(theta));*/

    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

your direction is right here:

```
BvelX = 0;
BvelY = -1;
```

this says go strait up

you probably want something like what is commented out

```
BvelY = 5*(Math.sin(theta));
BvelX = 5*(Math.cos(theta));
```

Since your positions are integer, you will not be able to go exactly the direction you are pointing.  Maybe you should store doubles, but draw integers.  Then you could get the bullet to travel closer to theta.

Answer (score 0):

Well it goes up because:

```
BvelX = 0;
BvelY = -1;
```

And when you update:

```
bx += BvelX;
by += BvelY;
```

So `y` is decremented (so it goes up) but `x` always stays the same (so it doesn't go left or right)

Comment: And I also have a rotate with the graphicsS.rotate(theta, bx, by);  How come that does not do anything?

Comment: because you never update `theta` so it stays the same. You need to do the same as for `bx` and `by`

Comment: Right after ´by += BvelY;´ add somerhing like ´theta +=10;´